# How can i manually trigger kernel Null pointer dereference error?

Tags: macos, kernel

I am working on an application for which I need to trigger a kernel null pointer de-reference error and check that in logs.

I'm not familiar as to how to do that.

Comment: Are you asking how to attach a debugger and inject bad values to cause a crash?

Comment: If it's a generic panic you're after, not necessarily a NULL pointer dereference, you can force it via dtrace. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829277/48660

Answer (score 1):

Without installing extra software, you would need to find a kernel bug (and/or exploit). You could use an older version of macOS with known bugs/exploits, and use one of those.

Alternatively you could add a kernel extension of your own, and then do a null pointer dereference in that.